# Connect python script to mysql in docker

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I wanna connect my python script to MySQL in docker.
Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:${MARIADB_VERSION:-latest}
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-password}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER:-root}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE:-db}
    restart: always

  script:
    container_name: script
    build: ./test_db
    command: bash -c "python3 testDb.py"
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=db
      - HOST=mysql
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./test_db:/var/www/html/script
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

and here is my Python script file:

```py
import pymysql

class TestDb:
    def run(self):
        conn = pymysql.connect(host='mysql', port=3306, database='db', user='root', password='password')
        print(conn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestDb().run()
```

and here is my error:

```
script    | Traceback (most recent call last):
script    |   File "/test_db/testDb.py", line 10, in <module>
script    |     TestDb().run()
script    |   File "/test_db/testDb.py", line 5, in run
script    |     conn = pymysql.connect(host='mysql', port=3306, database='sta_db', user='root', password='Alphashadow1381')
script    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
script    |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
script    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__
script    |     self.connect()
script    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 619, in connect
script    |     raise exc
script    | pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

How can I connect my Python script to MySQL in docker?

Comment: try posting the result of docker-compose ps

Comment: Does it work if you run `docker-compose up -d`, wait 30-60 seconds, and run the same command again?  In the log file you already have, are there either error messages from the database, or database startup messages after the Python error you quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that the ports are not open, or a problem with the hostname!

you haven't exposed the ports to the outside world, maybe add this line

```
services:

  mysql:
    image: mariadb:${MARIADB_VERSION:-latest}
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-password}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER:-root}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-password}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE:-db}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, you saved me from a nightmare!

Comment: anytime :))))))

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to open your ports
add this to your docker-copose:
ports:
- "3306:3306"